# WCF Soap Service Deserialization failed (unrecognized element was encountered)

Tags: wcf, web-services, soap

I build a WCF selfhosted WS (basichttp-binding) with 2 methods. Then created a WSDL and delivered it to a customer. Now they are sending SOAP-requests to the service but one of my methods (PostSendeplatz) fails everytime with a null parameter. In the trace I see the following:

```
<TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Verbose">
  <TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-DE/library/System.Runtime.Serialization..aspx</TraceIdentifier>
  <Description>An unrecognized element was encountered in the XML during deserialization which was ignored.</Description>
  <AppDomain>RabbitServerTopSelf.vshost.exe</AppDomain>
  <ExtendedData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/08/ServiceModel/StringTraceRecord">
    <Element>http://plantri.de:sendeplatz</Element>
  </ExtendedData>
</TraceRecord>
```

I checked my namespaces in DataContracts, ServiceContract and ServiceImplementation:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://plantri.de")]
public interface IRabbitImportService {
    [OperationContract]
    bool PostSendung(Sendung sendung, out string errorMsg);

    [OperationContract]
    bool PostSendeplatz(Sendeplatz sendePlatz, out string errorMsg);
}
...
[DataContract(Namespace = "http://plantri.de")]
public class Sendeplatz : RabbitIdBase { ...
...
[DataContract(Namespace = "http://plantri.de")]
public class Sendung : RabbitIdBase { ...
...
[ServiceBehavior(Namespace="http://plantri.de")]
public class RabbitImportService : Log4NetLogWriter, IRabbitImportService {
...
public bool PostSendung(Sendung sendung, out string errorMsg) {
... do something and return success
}

public bool PostSendeplatz(Sendeplatz sendePlatz, out string errorMsg) {
  errorMsg = String.Empty;

  if (sendePlatz == null) {
    Error("no Sendeplatz send!");
    return false;
  }
  ... never came until this point!!!!
}
```

Here is a part of the soap-envelope which isn't deserialized (from the trace):

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <s:Header xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <To s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://192.168.40.64:8800/RabbitImportService</To>
        <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://plantri.de/IRabbitImportService/PostSendeplatz</Action>
    </s:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <PostSendeplatz xmlns="http://plantri.de">
            <sendeplatz>
                <Id>1258878</Id>
...
```

But the working envelope looks quite the same:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <s:Header xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <To s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://192.168.40.64:8800/RabbitImportService</To>
        <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://plantri.de/IRabbitImportService/PostSendung</Action>
    </s:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <PostSendung xmlns="http://plantri.de">
            <sendung>
                <Id>564589</Id>
...
```

I don't have a chance to change the client proxy which was writen by a customer (JAVA).
Did anyone have an idea to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

But the working envelope looks quite the same:     How?

```
      <PostSendeplatz xmlns="http://plantri.de">
        <sendeplatz>

      <PostSendung xmlns="http://plantri.de">
        <sendung>
```

I see these tag names differs.